# Association does not work in both ways

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Greetings good people!

I want to link 2 models through another model:

```rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...some callbacks...

  has_many :article_images, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :images, through: :article_images

  ...some methods...
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...some callbacks...

  has_many :article_images, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :articles, through: :article_images

  ...other methods...
end

class ArticleImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :image
end
```

This works fine when I try to relate an article with an image using << or create():

```rb
art = Article.find 2 #=> <Article id: 2, category: 14, template: 2, param: "2">    
art.images #=> <ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []

img = Image.find 2 #=> <Image id: 2, filename: "testna2.jpg">   
art.images << img #=> <ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Image id: 2, filename: "testna2.jpg">]>
```

The problem occurs when I try to do this the other way around:

```rb
img = Image.find 2
img.articles #=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

I didn't even come to the part where I assign an image object to a the article, looks like the association only works in one direction - art.images returns a collection, but img.articles causes an error.

Here's the crucial part of my schema (using mySQL):

```rb
create_table "articles", force: true do |t|
  t.integer "category"
  t.integer "template"
  t.string  "param"
end

create_table "article_images", force: true do |t|
  t.integer "article_id"
  t.integer "image_id"
  t.string  "lang"
  t.string  "title"
  t.text    "desc"
end

create_table "images", force: true do |t|
  t.string "filename"
end
```

Here's the trace (seems like the problem isn't caused by my models?):

```rb
2.0.0p247 :023 > img.articles
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
    from /home/ziga/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@goopti-storefront/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:70:in `articles'
from (irb):23
from /home/ziga/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@goopti-storefront/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /home/ziga/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@goopti-storefront/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /home/ziga/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@goopti-storefront/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone have a clue what's going on? At first I used **has_and_belongs_to_many** to connect the Article and Image models, but then I figured it would be better to include a third model with some extra columns (apart from the ids). That doesn't seem to be such a good idea now...

Comment: It seem s like you overrode articles method somewhere else. Do you declare 'articles' method or scope within Image model?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your associations. Did you perhaps override the `articles method` on your `Image model`?

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, but unfortunately I don't override the articles method, nor do I use scope. I doublechecked. 
I just call the articless method on an <Image> object in my Image model and that's where I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, looks like i found out what causes the error, but I'm still not sure why - I was using an **attr_accessor** in my code and it seems like the problem was it's name.

I changed the

```rb
attr_accessor :association
```

into

```rb
attr_accessor :assoc
```

and my problem was suddenly gone, although the method that was using the **@association** variable was commented out even before I did the renaming.

I am still not sure how can an **attr_accessor** effect the model and the association, but I think that **"association"** might be a reserved word in rails (couldn't find it on any list though).

If anyone is having trouble with the same thing, then I'd suggest you to check your code for suspicious attr_accessors or variable and method names.

I still can't make a final conclusion about what happened, so please do leave a comment if you think you know something about this issue :)